# Intellij-IDEA selects the wrong maven dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

I have used IDEA for some time and recently I updated to version 2018.1.1 from 2016.3. So it seems as if IDEA have gotten smarter, but not to my pleasure I am afraid.

So basically I have started to run into a lot of troubles lately. I have for example noted that when there are possible issues with the unit tests (eg. TestNG tests) there are currently two things that happens

1) Maven cannot find the jar (which btw builds perfectly from command line using mvn clean install)

2) Maven reverts to the latest working jar.

If I then try to reimport, I will go directly to (2). I also get weird error where commercial libraries such as guava generates errors.

I have never seen this until I upgraded IDEA Intellij. Anyone that have an suggestion on that might cause this and how to solve the problem.

The behavior I want is that the version marked out in the pom is imported with all the possible flaws, like it use to do. Then I can find the errors and fix them. I should also point out that, `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip` works perfectly from command line, so not dependency issues with production code.

maven 3.3.9

jdk 1.8_172-b11

**EDIT**

I must mention that I use the "import maven projects automatically" feature here, which might explain (2), but I can still not see how this issue appears in the first place. Apart from changing IDEA version previously I have not had any problems in finding SNAPSHOTs.

**EDIT 2**
So the problem was indeed a pom error. I am not sure how eclipse managed to find the "correct" file (which was btw, *not* the correct file). After updating the pom it all worked out. I will not mention this here, since the behavior was a bit obscure (and I am not sure I understand it really). It have something to do with versions of the libraries, dependencyManagment, submodules and dependencies from submodules.

BR
Patrik

Comment: Are they SNAPSHOT or release dependency versions? and are you trying to pull them locally from your development pc, or from a repo? Any parts of the pom.xml you can share with us?

Comment: @vikingsteve they are SNAPSHOTs, I forgot to add that, but just finished my edit. But I have never had problems in finding SNAPSHOTs before (and neither does command line maven). They are stored locally. However, I do not think it would be meaningful to share the pom (due to maven itself building well).

Comment: Try the "Reimport all Maven Projects" button (top left in "Maven Projects" window) after everytime you rebuild the snapshot.

Comment: @vikingsteve I have tried that already. It did not work. I am currently thinking about reverting to the older version of IntelliJ still working. This would be the solution unless I can get the current version to work the old one did.

Comment: You restarted intelliJ? Also check your ´.m2/repository/path/to/your/artifact´ folder that no "Lock" file exists. It should work. Works for me all the time.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to delete the whole /repository directory at the same time as I tried "Invalidate caches". For some reason it views the SNAPSHOT version as broken, even though no other tool does so. Also, the tests do fail. That is not related to the IntelliJ problems, but to Mockito2. But this is a runtime error, so it should not affect the IntelliJ import.

Comment: I am actually inclined to write a bugreport on this as well, but that would take a long time to get solved and the jetbrains team might call it a "feature". I am of course still thankful for all suggestions :).